# How to force pandas DataFrame use the desired dtypes when it is constructed?

Tags: python, pandas

For example:

```
raw = {'x':[1,2,3,4], 'y':[None,]*4, 'z':[datetime.now()] *4, 'e':[1,2,3,4]}

a = pd.DataFrame(raw, dtype={'x':float, 'y':float, 'z':object, 'e':int})
```

This doesn't work.

Currently I have to do:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(raw, dtype=object)
a['x'] = a['x'].astype(float)
a['y'] = a['y'].astype(float)
a['z'] = pd.to_date_time(a['z'], utc=True)
a['e'] = a['e'].astype(int)
```

Since I have a number of `raw` objects I would like to cast into dataframe, is there an easy way to force the right `dtypes` at constructing time, instead of transforming them later, which takes 2x time needed.

@Jeff has a good way to deal with `raw` if it is in dict format.

But what if `raw` is in records format, like:

```
raw = [(1,None,datetime.now(),1),
       (2,None,datetime.now(),2), 
       (3,None,datetime.now(),3),
       (4,None,datetime.now(),4)]
```

Do I have to `zip` it? Perhaps the time taken for `zip` would cost more than cast again afterwards?
`DataFrame.from_records` doesn't seem to accept a `dtype` parameter at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor will infer non-ambiguous types correctly. You cannot specify a compound dtype mapping ATM, issue is [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4464), pull-requests are welcome to implement this.

- Don't use `None`, instead use `np.nan` (otherwise it will infer to `object` dtype)
- Specify floats with a decimal point (or wrap as a Series, e.g. `Series([1,2,3,4],dtype='float')`
- datetimes will automatically infer to `datetime64[ns]` which is almost always what you want unless you need to specify a timezone

Here's your example

```
In [20]: DataFrame({
    'x':Series([1,2,3,4],dtype='float'), 
    'y':Series([None,]*4,dtype='float'), 
    'z':[datetime.datetime.now()] *4, 
    'e':[1,2,3,4]})
Out[20]: 
   e  x   y                          z
0  1  1 NaN 2014-06-17 07:40:42.188422
1  2  2 NaN 2014-06-17 07:40:42.188422
2  3  3 NaN 2014-06-17 07:40:42.188422
3  4  4 NaN 2014-06-17 07:40:42.188422

In [21]: DataFrame({
     'x':Series([1,2,3,4],dtype='float'), 
     'y':Series([None,]*4,dtype='float'), 
     'z':[datetime.datetime.now()] *4, 
     'e':[1,2,3,4]}).dtypes
Out[21]: 
e             int64
x           float64
y           float64
z    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make it clear. I cannot control the types in `raw`. It comes as it is.